# windows phone 8 app for sending SMS from windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, sms

I am developing a simple windows phone 8 app using visual studio express 2012 and WP8 SDK using C# and SQLite. I would like to know how to send SMS or email to various recipients using this app with my windows phone (I do not want to send SMS through internet ) 
thanks a lotttt :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't send an SMS or an email (from system account) without user approval. To do that use Launchers:

**Email**: Use `EmailComposeTask`: [How to use the email compose task for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

**SMS**: Use `SmsComposeTask`: [How to use the SMS compose task for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394005%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

They both shows popup and ask user to approve the message to be send.

Answer (score 0):

in windows phone 8.1 i use the following code in C#:

```
        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
        chatMessage.Body = "Text message";
        chatMessage.Recipients.Add("phonenumber");

        await   ChatMessageManager.ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync(chatMessage);
```

Hope it helps :)